# Meaning of ~ in import of scss files

Tags: sass, webpack

I have a npm library that I use for styling which uses the following syntax to import scss files. I am not sure what this means and could not find any documentation online. I use grunt with webpack during my build process.

```
@import '~bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon';
@import '~bourbon-neat';
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From documentation on a [sass-loader#imports](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader#imports) project,

> webpack provides an advanced mechanism to resolve files. The
>   sass-loader uses node-sass' custom importer feature to pass all
>   queries to the webpack resolving engine. Thus you can import your Sass
>   modules from node_modules. Just prepend them with a ~ to tell webpack
>   that this is not a relative import

So if you have a file named `foo.css` and a module `foo` then you would use `~` if you want to include the module.