# What does the ~ in front of the SASS/SCSS @import mean/do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, sass

I was told on GitHub to start using a `~` before my SASS/SCSS `@import` paths. Tried to Google it but couldn't find a proper answer. I guess it's too newbie to even bother writing about, but I would like to learn it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of ~ in import of scss files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880187/meaning-of-in-import-of-scss-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to the **`node_modules`** directory (or its equivalent).

For instance, in an Angular app (which uses node.js and webpack, of course) you could have this:

A `nav-bar.component.scss` which references (`@import`) `~bootstrap/scss/functions`.

The `~` part refers to `node_module` and the rest of it (`bootstrap/scss/functions`) refers to the rest of the path inside the `node_module` directory (see images below)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

~ is a relative reference to your code files.

~ refers to node_modules when we import angular material themes and other libraries.
while in case of ~ in case of SASS references to your local files to load your partials. for eg: @import '~scss/variables';
Generally its a default location reference to the file system. I am not sure about the correct terminologies.

Answer (score 0):

Its webpack feature.
`~` is equals to `node_modules`