# SCSS `@import '~src/` or `src/`

Tags: sass

In SCSS, which is better?

1. `@import '~src/styles/variables';`
2. `@import 'src/styles/variables';`

Is the `~` necessary?

Comment: Is this link what you are looking to find out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880187/meaning-of-in-import-of-scss-files

Comment: `~/` means **root directory of application**. `/` means **site root**. Nothing is better or worse, it just depends on your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

The `~` prefix is used with tools such as webpack to distinguish alias resolution from library resolution.

Use `~` with your aliases, otherwise prefer relative imports